# Combine rows into columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table customer(id_customer, email, id_default_group) and product_list(id_item,id_product,id_group,product_title,image,html_product,price,reduced_price,reduction_pourcentage) and banner_list(id_banner,id_group,html)
I would like to join the table with the id_group
I would like to get all email from customer and all informations from product_list and banner_list where customer.id_group = id_group from product_list and banner_list,

All this i can get it from a simple sql query, but i would like to get the result array in a particular form,

Expected result row: 
email,
product_title_1,image_1,html_product_1,price_1,reduced_price_1,reduction_pourcentage_1, product_title_2,.....,reduction_pourcentage_2, product_title_n, .....,reduction_pourcentage_n,banner_list.html_1,banner_list.html_2,banner_list.html_z

I tried with this php code, but it doen't give me what i want

```
 for($i=1;$i<$nb_product;$i++){
        $sql = 'SELECT  c.`email`
             FROM  `'._DB_PREFIX_.'customer` c
            UNION ALL
            Select 
            pl.title,pl.image,pl.html,pl.price,pl.price_barre,pl.pourcentage 
            FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_list` pl
             WHERE 1 '.Shop::addSqlRestriction(Shop::SHARE_CUSTOMER).' and pl.id_item='.$i.' and pl.id_group =c.id_default_group
                                ORDER BY c.`id_customer` ASC';

        $res[]= Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot have differing numbers of columns in UNIONs

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.